# Java date object returning 30 as the month?

Tags: java, algorithm

Why is this code giving me trouble?

```
public Date setupDate(){
        String startDateString ="05/10/2010 04:30:20";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = null;
        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
            System.err.println(newDateString);
            System.err.println(startDate.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return startDate;
    }
```

output:

```
SEVERE:   30/10/2010 04:30:20
SEVERE:   Sun Jan 10 04:30:20 EST 2010
```

I expected May 10 of course, not January(I don't know how it became January, or the 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the section [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You should use

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

`M` is for Month in year while `m` is for minute in hour

Answer (score 1):

The format symbol for month uses capital `M`; you've used minutes `m` twice, which is `30` here.  For reference, here's the [Javadocs that explain all format symbols for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).